# Is there reduced water supply due to reduction in pipeline diameter?

Tags: flow

I have a 3" water pipeline length 80'coming in from municipal supply, say pipe A, to my water meter. After the water meter, a 2.5" pipeline goes 160' to my underground water tank, say pipe B. Water just fall into the tank. Entire water line is at ground level, with no changes in elevation. There is a non-return valve in pipe A.

Pls advice me whether I am loosing water supply because of the dia of pipe B?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the same pressure and length, flow does depend on the pipe diameter, but I would think 2.5" pipe should be more than enough for domestic needs: even if sometimes you need higher flow, your tank would help meet the greater demand for a limited time. The pipe diameter would matter if it were too small to provide the required amount of water even if the pipe were open round the clock.